# Opencart 1.5.5.1 header menu linking directly to first subcategory

Tags: php, mysql, menu, opencart, categories

I'm currently looking for help with linking the main category links in the header menu directly to their first subcategory.

In other words:

when clicking on the category link I would like to add the ID of the first subcategory at the end, i.e.

```
route=product/category&path=18_59
```

instead of

```
route=product/category&path=18
```

Does anyone has a suggestion how to do that?

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
          <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to **StackOverflow**!

This could be achieved by getting the first child of the main category and we have two options, one cleaner and one easier.

**The cleaner one**. This would require the changes in the `catalog/controller/common/header.php` and model `catalog/model/catalog/category.php`, let's go on step by step. First, add the new necessary function into the category model:

```
public function getCategoryFirstChildId($category_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT category_id FROM '. DB_PREFIX .'category WHERE parent_id = '. (int)$category_id .' ORDER BY category_id ASC LIMIT 1');

    return $query->row['category_id'];
}
```

This function will get all the categories where `parent_id` is the `$category_id` given as a parameter, sort them ascending by `category_id` (You can change that to whatever sorting You want) and return only the first one.

Now let's go to the controller - we will edit the part where categories are loaded:

```
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['top']) {
            // Level 2
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );                      
            }

/*NEW =>*/  $first_child_id = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryFirstChildId($category['category_id']);

            // Level 1
            $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $first_child_id)
//     >>>          >>>          >>>           >>>          >>>           >>>          >>>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            );
        }
    }
```

This should be it. Be wise that this though cleaner way requires one more DB query per category thus may slow down (though a tiny bit) the site when large number of categories is being processed.

**The easier way** - need changes to be done only within header controller (no new function is added to the model):

```
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['top']) {
            // Level 2
            $children_data = array();
/*NEW =>*/  $first_child_id = 0;
/*NEW =>*/  $first_child = true;

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
/*NEW =>*/      if($first_child) {
/*NEW =>*/          $first_child = false;
/*NEW =>*/          $first_child_id = $child['category_id'];
/*NEW =>*/      }

                $data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );                      
            }

            // Level 1
            $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $first_child_id)
//     >>>          >>>          >>>           >>>          >>>           >>>          >>>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            );
        }
    }
```

The easier way will also work very well and would be a little quicker but the first category it will point to will always be the one that comes as first when sorting ascending by `sort_order` - whenever it may change, the main category will point to a different child category...

I didn't test neither of the ways but I believe they will work on 100%.

Comment: Thank you very much for this perfect guide! I tried the cleaner version and it worked perfectly (as soon as I created subcategories for all the categories, of course.. ;o)

Comment: You are welcome! Do not hesitate to come back again should You encounter any further problem(s).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to say that my current reputation doesn't allow me to vote your answer up.. :o/